# how to combine merge_range and write_formula with xlsxwriter python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

this is the code that i'm trying. but its not working.

```
import xlsxwriter
....
sheet.merge_range.write_formula('F16:H16', """IF('Original data'!B4<>"",'Original data'!B4,"")""", center)
```

Is there another code that can put both of them become one? i'm already doing some research and don't get any. thanks in advance

Comment: You have asked a series of questions on XlsxWriter that are covered in the [documentation](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/index.html) and examples. It would probably save you some time if you read the documentation and looked through the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs on [merge_range()](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#merge_range):

> The merge_range() method writes its data argument using write(). Therefore it will handle numbers, strings and formulas as usual. If this doesn’t handle your data correctly then you can overwrite the first cell with a call to one of the other write_*() methods using the same Format as in the merged cells. See Example: [Merging Cells with a Rich String](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_merge_rich.html#ex-merge-rich).

Here is a small working example based on yours:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('example.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet('Original data')

center = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center', 'fg_color': 'yellow'})


worksheet1.merge_range('F16:H16',
                       """=IF('Original data'!B4<>"",'Original data'!B4,"")""",
                       center)

worksheet2.write('B4', 'Hello')

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]